# Allow zero, allow number, and maximum two number after point

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to write regex validation.
Accepted numbers:
0
0.3
0.21
78.21
8934

Not Allowed:
00
0.323
-1
021

```
^(?:0,\d\d|[1-9]\d*(?:,\d\d)?|)$
```

I had that regex, but it doesn't accept '0', and number '0.2'.

Answer (score 1):

Seems the following ticks your boxes:

```
^(?:0|[1-9]\d*)(?:\.\d\d?)?$
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/IaaUgr/1)

- `^` - Start line anchor.
- `(?:` - Open non-capture group:

  - `0` - A literal "0".
  - `|` - Or:
  - `[1-9]\d*` - A single digit ranging 1-9 followed by 0+ digits.
  - `)` - Close non-capture group.
- `(?:` - Open 2nd non-capture group:

  - `\.\d\d?` - Match a literal "." followed by a digit and an optional 2nd digit.
  - `)?` - Close non-capture group and make it optional.
- `$` - End line anchor.